# Problems debugging my own binarytree adt in c

Tags: c

```
       typedef struct btNode {
            struct btNode *right;
            struct btNode *left;
            void  *data;
        } btNode_t;

       typedef struct binTree
        {
            btNode_t *root;
            btNode_t *current;

        } binTree_t;

        int buildBintree(binTree_t *tree)
            {
               tree = (binTree_t*) malloc(sizeof(binTree_t));
               if (tree == NULL)
                return ERROR;
               tree->root = NULL;
               tree->current = NULL;
               return SUCCESS;
            }
```

I need to insert the first leaf in my binary tree, but i dont know why my program crushes when i try to to make an **if** to ask if the tree->current is pointed to null in the leaf creating function.

```
int buildLeaf(binTree_t *tree, void *info)
            {
                if ((tree->current) != NULL)
                    return ERROR;

                btNode_t *btnode;

                btnode = (btNode_t*) malloc(sizeof(btNode_t));

                if (btnode == NULL)
                        return ERROR;

                if (isEmptyBintree(tree))
                    tree->root = btnode;

                tree->current = btnode;

                tree->current->data = info;
                tree->current->left = NULL;
                tree->current->right = NULL;

                return SUCCESS;
            }
```

I have my tree empty and i only want to add the first leaf if the current has not a filled node

```
        int main()
            {
               binTree_t *maple;
                int number;

                buildBintree(maple);
                buildLeaf(maple,&number);

               return 0;


            }
```

Comment: Post your full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buildBintree should receive double pointer. Using single pointer, tree will  not point to maple, which is actually pointing to object which maple is pointing.

```
   int buildBintree(binTree_t **tree)
        {
           *tree = (binTree_t*) malloc(sizeof(binTree_t));
           if (*tree == NULL)
            return -1;

           (*tree)->root = NULL;
           (*tree)->current = NULL;
           return 0;
        }
```

and in main you need to call like below.

```
           int main()
            {
               binTree_t *maple;
                int number;

                buildBintree(&maple);

                buildLeaf(maple,&number);
               return 0;
            }
```

Comment: I agree with the change, although it might be clearer if you allocated the memory into a new binTree_t* and saved the value in the output argument at the end, rather than working with `*tree` throughout. (Or you could just return the binTree_t* instead.)

Comment: buildBintree(&maple);

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about pointers.

Regardless of its type, assigning a new value to a parameter has no effect on any variable whose value you passed in.
(What do you expect to happen if you `buildBinTree(NULL);`?)

If you want a function to modify something, you need to pass it the address of the thing that's going to change.
So if you want the function to modify a pointer, you need to pass it the address of a pointer.

```
int x = 0;
void fail(int* p) { p = &x; }
void succeed(int** p) { *p = &x; }

int main()
{
    int *p = NULL;
    fail(p);
    /* p is still null */
    succeed(&p);
    /* p is not null any more */
    return 0;
}
```